Using typescript types from the @types folder in Nuxt3
From what I understand. The suggested way to use JavaScript libraries in TypeScript is to install the corresponding *.d.ts files from npm. These are usually found in the @types/ namespace.
This works really well when I'm creating my own TypeScript projects.
When I use Vite and request TypeScript it takes one extra step - I need to add "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts" to the includes property in the supplied tsconfig.json.
However Nuxt maintains its own autogenerated tsconfig.json (which the local file extends). Trying to add an include property overwrites the nuxt include which means TypeScript imports nothing by default.
So where can I put the directive to include "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"?
More importantly, why isn't that the default?
How do I have TypeScript pickup the declarations in the @types/ folder?

B"H
Surprising workaround. I figured out how to make this work with a small tweak.
I tried everything, that everyone suggested. Nothing worked. Until I realized that if I added a /// <reference path="" /> to any *.ts file in my project, it made those types available to all files.
So I new have a file called ambient.ts tucked away in my local types folder,and every time I added a library from StaticallyTyped I add a row to that file like this
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/gapi/index.d.ts" />

Now the types are available in every file throughout my project.

Nuxt allows to customize .nuxt/tsconfig.json by config.
nuxt.config.ts:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  typescript: {
    tsConfig: {
      compilerOptions: {
        types: ['node'], // means including @types/node
      },
    },
  },
});

demo

First of all: It doesn't work. I tried what you said, and there's no change. Still getting Cannot find name 'gapi'.ts-plugin(2304) in vscode.
Second of all: Why in the world would you need to add every type library that you have to a configuration file? Once it know to look in the @types folder, why doesn't it pickup the trypes there? That's the way TypeScript is built to work.
